# Infinity in modern integration theory

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, infinity

The Riemann integral itself doesn't work with infinity (±∞) as “endpoints”, you have to take a detour by calculating the integral for arbitrary endpoints ±*z* and then take the limit for *z*→∞, which makes it an “improper” integral.

In effect, with ℝ as domain of integration the following holds:

- With the improper Riemann integral you have to calculate *two*
  limits, a limit of a sequence and then the limit of a
  function towards infinity.
- But with the Lebesgue integral only one limit, that of a sequence, is necessary.

Still, not always does a Lebesgue integral exist when an improper Riemann integral exists, e.g. sin(*x*)/*x* with endpoints ±∞ (this is the ∞ - ∞ problem and can only occur for functions *f* where the integral of min(*f*, 0) is already -∞).

Now, in the context of the famous quote:

> ... first of all I must protest against the use of an infinite magnitude as a completed quantity, which is never allowed in mathematics. The Infinite is just a mannner of speaking, in which one is really talking in terms of limits, which certain ratios may approach as close as one wishes, while others may be allowed to increase without restriction. – C. F. Gᴀᴜss

can we say that the Lebesgue integral *does* achieve what Gᴀᴜss declares to be impossible?

***Obviously,* infinity is approached differently with the Lebesgue integral than with the improper Riemann integral.**

But how? What is the exact *philosophical* difference?

PS: sorry, if that question gets closed here as off-topic because it's too mathematical, it will also certainly get closed as off-topic on math.SE for  not being mathematical enough (the same happened with my “fair lottery of the natural numbers” question).

Comment: Lebesgue theory still treats limits in Cauchy's sense, as arbitrarily close approximations rather than real or completed infinities.

Comment: The "standard" approach to infinity in *calculus* and *analysis* is that expressed by Gauss : *infinity* is only a "facon de parler"  that must be replaced with the formal rigorous notion of *limit*.

Comment: Things are different in set theory, from Cantor and on, where infinite "objects" are treated mathematically and the concept of *number* is "stretched" to allows for infinite numbers.

Comment: Lebesgue integral just uses a more flexible approximation process. When you are approximating your function by simple functions you have to choose 0 values for them at the tails, and successively move their edge points outward. This effectively packages the two limits Riemann takes into a single scheme (there is also a difference in approximating on finite intervals, but I assume that is beside the point). This is not salient to "completed infinity", which Cantor openly endorsed already, and the measure theory presupposes anyway.

Comment: @Conifold well, but why then aren't all improper Riemann integrals also Lebesgue integrals? There must be a different conception behind infinity, maybe not completed vs. potential, but in some other way.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what about the indicator function with f(x) = 1 for x ∈ ℚ and f(x) = 0 otherwise? Its Lebesgue integral is zero.

Comment: Because Lebesgue first decomposes functions into positive and negative parts, and demands that both integrals exist. This is because he wants nice closure properties for integrable functions. The improper Riemann integrals that are not Lebesgue integrals are those where positive and negative parts are infinite. This is similar to conditionally convergent series, in the big picture they behave badly  - rearranging the terms can produce any desired sum, as Riemann proved. Of course, one may well define improper Lebesgue integral, if one wants it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "Where infinite 'objects' are treated mathematically and the concept of number is 'stretched' to allow for infinite numbers," are your really sure about that?

Comment: It may not be with improper integrals which use limits where a completed infinity is relevant but with the measure of sets on the domain. Riemann did not need a measure of these sets. He just took a small line segment, delta x, and let that get small. The indicator function you mention needs to know to assign a measure of 0 to sets in the domain that have countable cardinality such as Q. This would mean the difference in approaching infinity would be relevant even on [0,1] for the indicator function f(x)=1 for x in Q and f(x)=0 otherwise.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Mauro's comment seems completely correct to me, if not too specific. Are you familiar with [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)? These are really the bread-and-butter of set theory, they're infinite (well, most of them are), and calling them "numbers" definitely stretches the term.

Comment: @NoahSchweber ordinal "number" is really a misnomer. Ordinal "numbers" is just the generalization of the "SET" of natural numbers. There no number s.t. we define it as "infinite." Infinities in the realm of mathematics is just that, a concept used for "really really big number."

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost Your first two sentences are contingent on your own view of the meaning of the term "number," which is **not** in fact universal amongst mathematicians. Your third sentence is simply incorrect: an infinite group (for example) is not just a group with a really really big number of elements, and we distinguish meaningfully between different types of infinity.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost The line "infinity isn't a number, it's an idea" is a common slogan, and it's definitely useful for dispelling early confusions about how to reason about infinity. But it relies on that same limited notion of "number" that set theory helps deconstruct - and even if one doesn't buy the idea of "number" applying to a broader context the realization that infinities can be treated rigorously on their own as precise entities is **absolutely crucial**. (Also, when you write "infinities in the realm of mathematics ...," are you saying that set theory *isn't* mathematics?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I do not want to keep going back and forth especially in a comment chain, but I have a feeling you will, pun intended, tend to cardinality. A number is just the elements of subsets of certain sets whose cardinality could be a number, but which is not really necessary.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost To quote the great Californian mathematician, "That's just, like, your opinion, man." Seriously though, you don't speak for all of mathematics. **You** may have certain views about what numbers are; that doesn't mean they're universally shared, and simply asserting them as fact isn't ideal philosophical practice. If you ask a question about different views of "number" here, I'll gladly elaborate on some of the other perspectives. But suffice to say that Mauro was exactly right: whether you approve or not, the concept of "number" is indeed "stretched" in set theory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Neither are you speaking for all mathematics (at least the branches I am speaking for are quite useful in the empirical sciences); Which means your definition is unrealaistic, at most axiomatic, without empirical support. However, I can give you reasons for what I said (both mathematical & philosophical), but Its kind of tedious tbh. Especially in a comment chain. For now, let us agree to disagree!✌

Answer (score 1):

> The Riemann integral doesn’t work well infinity as endpoints ...

In fact it does, you simply need to choose your space of functions carefully. Generally this is the space of continuous compactly supported functions. These are functions that are zero as you go towards infinity. The space of continuous rapidly decreasing functions is another.

It’s because the function is bounded in both directions that we can make sense of its area in a simple way, when it’s not, then other strategies need to be adopted. This is just as much a problem of the Lesbegue integral as it is for the Riemann integral.

The question of how to make *sense* of improper integrals has nothing to do with infinity - other than to notice that it is saying that the theory breaks down here - and it is all about how to understand the *meaning* of integration and this makes it a question of mathematics and how to understand the maths in mathematics rather than philosophy.

**edit**

The other small point to make, but relevant to the discussion, is that the Lesbegue integral is also defined in a two step process, essentially because it allows infinity as a value. But since infinity - infinity is undefined the standard method of defining the Lesbegue integral calculates it first for positive part of a function and then for the negative part and then subtracts the two.